# Will I be able to use the pro fields in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a question, can someone tell me or tell me where to read about it, I bought a laravel backpack everything license a year ago, after graduation I will be able to use the fields of the pro version or not. Nothing could be found on the laravel backpack website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install and use it up to the version you have, but not the new updates, you need to lock your composer.json so it downloads the last version you have access to (e.g. "backpack/pro":"2.0.8").